# Error resolving Resolving org.apache#apache;4

Tags: maven

I'm running Spark Notebook and struggling with dependancies. The server runs in an Amazon VPC, so has no direct Internet access.

In order to load dependancies, created a repo in an S3 bucket and this works fine, getting all the POM's and JAR's until it gets to

```
Installing the s3:// URLStreamHandler via
java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory

Creating a new Ivy URLHandlerDispatcher to handle s3:// URLs
[info] :: resolving dependencies :: org.scala-lang#scala;2.10.4
[info]  confs: [compile, test, runtime]
[info] Resolving default#ffx-analytics_2.10;1.1 ...
[info]  found default#ffx-analytics_2.10;1.1 in s3-repo
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 ...
[info]  found org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4 in s3-repo
[info]  [2.10.4] org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.4
[info] Resolving com.github.nscala-time#nscala-time_2.10;1.4.0 ...
[info]  found com.github.nscala-time#nscala-time_2.10;1.4.0 in s3-repo
[info] Resolving joda-time#joda-time;2.4 ...
[info]  found joda-time#joda-time;2.4 in s3-repo
[info] Resolving org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 ...
[info]  found org.joda#joda-convert;1.2 in s3-repo
[info] Resolving ua_parser#ua-parser;1.3.1-SNAPSHOT ...
[info]  found ua_parser#ua-parser;1.3.1-SNAPSHOT in s3-repo
[info] Resolving org.yaml#snakeyaml;1.10 ...
[info]  found org.yaml#snakeyaml;1.10 in s3-repo
[info] Resolving commons-collections#commons-collections;3.2.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-parent;9 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache#apache;4 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar
```

So I tried to download the JAR from another server (with internet access) like so:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-126-49-161:~$ wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar

--2015-09-07 00:37:42--  https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/4/apache-4.jar
Connecting to 172.16.100.11:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-09-07 00:37:45 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

I cant find an apache-4.jar anywhere. Looking at the POM there is no JAR for it.

Any tips would be appreciated.

UPDATE #1:

I tried importing another JAR that lead down a similar path:

```
[info] Resolving net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.0 ...
[info]  found net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.0 in s3-repo
[info] Resolving commons-codec#commons-codec;1.10 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache.commons#commons-parent;35 ...
[info] Resolving org.apache#apache;15 ...
```

When I look at the POM for Apache 35, it lists Apache 15 as a parent.

These parents appear to be a real nightmare. Hopefully it is just something simple I need to switch on to make this all work.

Comment: Please find this org.apache#apache dependency in one of your pom.xml files and write it here. There seems to be some dependency misconfiguration.

Comment: Also, is there a chance, that you created the pom.xml for org.apache#apache file in your S3 repository manually, instead of copying it from maven central? If so, it has to have `<packaging>pom</packaging>` in it, it seems like this line is either missing, or it is set to `<packaging>jar</packaging>`.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the POM and even refreshed it from maven central.  apache-4.pom:    <packaging>pom</packaging>

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here:
https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/using-ivy-with-pom-xml/

"Ivy ignores the packaging=pom on the parent module and will always try to find a .jar for it, thus wasting precious time. The workaround is to create a fake, empty .jar, for example via echo “” > emptyJarToSatisfyIvy.jar."